# Shell - Get interface name of IP address

Tags: bash, shell

Is there a way to query for the interface name of and IP address on Linux (GNU)? Vice versa this seems to be simple but I need it exactly the other way around, as I just have one IP address as input which is assigned to one of many interfaces of my system. How do I find out to which interface the input IP address belongs to?

imagin you have a script like that:

```
ips=($(hostname -I))

PS3='Please select a network the master should listen onto: '
ips=($(hostname -I))
ips=("${ips[@]}" 'Quit')
select ip in "${ips[@]}"; do
  case $ip in
    *[0-9]*)
      break
      ;;
    Quit) echo quit
      break;;
    *) echo Invalid option >&2;;
  esac
done

echo "IP: $ip has been choosen for enrollment"
```

And now you want to know the interface name of the selected ip address

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the command `ifconfig` show what you want?

Comment: Get the addresses of all the interfaces and see which one matches?

Comment: I updated my question, maybe I was a bit unclear of what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the output of `ip addr` using e.g. `awk` to find the interface name that has a certain ip address.  For example:

```
ip addr | awk -vtarget_addr=192.168.1.200 '
/^[0-9]+/ {
  iface=substr($2, 0, length($2)-1)
}

$1 == "inet" {
  split($2, addr, "/")
  if (addr[1] == target_addr) {
    print iface
  } 
}
'
```

This look for the interface with address 192.168.1.200. On my system, this will print:

```
vlan100
```

Because:

```
$ ip addr show vlan100
5: vlan100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 56:ba:dc:0f:73:69 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.200/32 brd 192.168.1.200 scope global noprefixroute vlan100
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.1.169/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute vlan100
       valid_lft 47960sec preferred_lft 47960sec
    inet6 fe80::acb6:be79:224e:3062/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Great for use in function, thx